# Animating tableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

*I want to animate table view cell during deleting the row.I am trying the following code, but the cell animation is not very good. How could i improve the animatin please help.*

My code is:

```
@objc func userLikeButtonWasTappaed(sender: UIButton){

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: sender.convert(sender.frame.origin, to: tableView)) else {
        return
    }

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MatchingUsersTVCell
    let tag = sender.tag

    if modelNameArray.count > 0{
        let userid = userIdArray[tag]
        totalScoreArray.remove(at: tag)
        modelNameArray.remove(at: tag)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
        }

        self.tableView.endUpdates()

        let uid: Int = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "User_Id") as! Int
        let accessToken: String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "access_token") as! String

        apiRequest.likeTheUser(uid, userid, accessToken) { (likedUser) in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes this "not good"? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it is working good. but some times it is going to right side and some times the animation going to buttom. some times, not every time.

Comment: i want to remove the perticular cell toward right. and next cell will take place of it, which will come from left side.

Comment: i also tried the following code. but it is not good also. 
                                                                                
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 15.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
            cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: -10, y: 1.6)

           }, completion: { (finished) in
               cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
       })

Comment: When looking for answers around intended UI animations, please consider including videos/gifs of what your UI is doing and possible examples of what is intended.

Comment: You're mixing up instructions regarding animation - you're telling the delegate methods to use a .right animation, you;re then wrapping that in a UIView animation, and finally your putting the whole thing in a begin/end updates block.  For a single instruction the begin/end aren't needed - remove them for starters.

Comment: When I am removing begin/end,the code working fine but some times instead of the particular cell, it’s before or after cells are animated.. why this is  happening. Sometimes instead of going right it is  going to button corner . Is there any problem in my code. Means code arrangement.